# Android studio keeps replacing match_parent with fixed dp value

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio (v 2.3.1) keeps replacing the `match_parent` of a RelativeLayout with a fixed dp vanue. For example, when I type match_parent as the width, it replaces it with 368dp. When I test the app, I see that the RelativeLayout indeed is wrong.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="be.mawey.lamachat.LoginActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" <!-- THIS IS BEING REPLACED WITH 368dp -->
        android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- THIS IS BEING REPLACED WITH 495dp -->
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="292dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextCode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Secret code here"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="234dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="example"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: keep maintain match_parent dont use fixed dp.

Comment: What do you mean? I do not use a fixed dp, Android studio just doesn't let me use match_parent

Comment: can u share your full xml file

Comment: The full xml file is added

Comment: It has to do something with constraint layout that you are using as a root layout,if you dont want it be changed try relative instead of constraint.

Comment: It is being replaced because for the current device or screen view this might be appropriate and it will change with change of device. that what the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html says.

Comment: The constraint layout was indeed the problem! Thank you Ashwandi! You can post this as a solution!

Comment: check the new answer

Comment: Follow the steps in rightclick of constraintLayout and chose constraint LAyout and chose Infer Constraints

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image]

Do it like as shown in picture

Answer (score 20):

**In short:**

You cannot use `match_parent` as the dimension for children of `ConstraintLayout`. You should use `0dp` which means "match_constraint" and constraint the sides to the parent's sides:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

---

**With a bit of background (or - from where I believe the confusion stems):**

Although I can't seem to find a proof, and my colleague claims I'm wrong - I'm certain [the android documentation for constraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) used to direct us, the developers, to use "either 0dp or match_parent" as values for a `layout_width` or `layout_height` to indicate that the corresponding view's dimension should be determined by the `constraintLayout` using the specified constraints (rather than using a specified fixed value or by determining its content's dimension). I'm also pretty sure I used this value (`match_parent`) in this manner and it worked before switching to AndroidStudio 2.3.1.

Whether I'm right or delusional, the fact is that currently [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) states:

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not supported for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout, though similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

Additionally, the `0dp` value is regarded the same as I remember it used to:

> The dimension of the widgets can be specified by setting the android:layout_width and android:layout_height attributes in 3 different ways:
>
> (...)
>
> - Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"

The editor, using "infer constraints" as in the answer of Sirnivas actually uses the `0dp` approach.

NOTE: "match_constraint" doesn't seem to be a value that can be used. `0dp` is what seems to be the actual value for the dimension to match the constraints.

Comment: You appear to be completely lucid (not delusional) as this is the correct answer and should have been marked as such. I tried the accepted answer.  It added meaningless extra attributes to the child layouts and *still* incorrectly hardcoded dp values.

Comment: Thank you @MylesBennett, good to know. As for the currently accepted answer - because it uses the visual editor it gives us as developers much less control and it can indeed infer additional unwanted values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/editTextCode"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="169dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextCode" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Secret code here"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="example"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This made my layout go crazy, the problem was the constraint layout