# setting width and height of ImageView to match_parent

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HDWX.jpg)i try to set layout_width and layout_height of ImageView to match_parent but it automatically changes to 274dp and 495dp. How to set them to match_parent?

Comment: Are you using constraint layout as parent ?

Comment: Post your code.  Unless you're doing weird, it shouldn't be any different to any other time you use match_parent

Comment: Please include your code an image of the situation to help others for better understanding.

Comment: Where you set it? In code or in xml? And what does it means "automatically changes"?

Comment: Did you set scaleMode to fitXy?

Comment: yeah i am using constraint layout as parent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio keeps replacing match\_parent with fixed dp value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452384/android-studio-keeps-replacing-match-parent-with-fixed-dp-value)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use match_parent as the dimension for children of ConstraintLayout. You should use 0dp which means "match_constraint" and constraint the sides to the parent's sides:

Choose one of two:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```